# How can I list all latin (English alphabet) characters?

Tags: c#, string

I am looking for an efficient way of getting a list with all English (latin) characters.

```
A, B, C, .... , Z
```

I really don't want a constructor like this:

```
// nasty way to create list of English alphabet
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("A");
list.Add("B");
....
list.Add("Z");

// use the list
...
```

If you are curius on how is this usable, I am creating a bin-tree mechanism.

Comment: Do you want a `List<string>` or a `List<char>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution (eventually)

```
const string driveLetters = "DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

List<string> allDrives = new List<string>(driveLetters.Length);
allDrives = (from letter
        in driveLetters.ToCharArray()
        select letter).ToList();
```

I ended up with this solution because initially my goal was to create a list of all available drives in windows. This is the actual code:

```
const string driveLetters = "DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const string driveNameTrails = @":\";

List<string> allDrives = (from letter
            in driveLetters.ToCharArray()
            select letter + driveNameTrails).ToList();

return allDrives;
```

Comment: So in the end you were just reinventing `System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()` ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman No. DriveInfo.GetDrives() gets a list with current drives. I wanted a list with all available. This will be used in an editor application. The current available drives are irrelevant.

Comment: OK. Short version: `allDrives = driveLetters.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList()`

Comment: As in my initial question. I need d:\ and not just d.
So your answer can become `allDrives = driveLetters.Select(c => c.ToString() + @":\").ToList()`

Answer (score 13):

You can do this with a `for` loop:

```
List<char> list = new List<char>();
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; ++c) {
    list.Add(c);
}
```

If you want a `List<string>` instead of a `List<char>` use `list.Add(c.ToString());` instead.

Note that this works only because the letters A - Z occur in a consecutive sequence in Unicode (code points 65 to 90). The same approach does not necessarily work for other alphabets.

Comment: This was my first though also. What I don't like in this listing, is that I am using ++ operator for characters. It is intended for numbers and that makes code nasty.

Comment: Characters are numbers and the character encoding defined by .net guarantees that A-Z are contiguous.

Comment: @odyodyo  There is nothing wrong with  `++` on a `char`. It is rare, that's all.

Answer (score 12):

Here:

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

This string is a list of characters.

Use either `ToCharArray` or the LINQ `ToList` to convert to an enumerable of your choice, though you can already access each item through the [`Chars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars.aspx) indexer of the string.

Comment: I think he needs a list, not the entire string.

Comment: @Tudor then just add a `ToList()` call. Or if you want a list of strings, `s.Select(c=>c.ToString()).ToList()`

Comment: @Tudor - What is a string but a list of characters?

Comment: @Tudor you can iterate the chars in the string (foreach char c in s..) it is a bona fide list of chars and you can toString each of them when/if you need strings

Comment: @Oded are you surprised that manually typing out all letters of the alphabet is disliked by some programmers?

Comment: @Tudor: `string` is `IEnumerable<char>`. That _is_ a basic List and easy to convert.

Comment: @CodeInChaos More likely it was pasted rather than typed. Let's not worry about maintenance issues since we can be sure that the letters of the English alphabet will not change.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - I just think people are completely unaware that you can iterate over the characters in a string, as Henk commented.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Well... in this case, I did type them all. But you are quite right - I am not expecting any new letters to be added to the English alphabet.

Answer (score 4):

Using LINQ

```
int charactersCount = 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
IList<char> all = Enumerable.Range('A', charactersCount)
                            .Union(Enumerable.Range('a', charactersCount))
                            .Select(i => (char)i)
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: As said in the previous answer's comment, I dont like using numeric operators for strings. This image won't be available to the rest of the team and might cause confusion. I must admit I like your answer.

Comment: -1 for magic values. Since `char` is implicitly convertible to `int`, just use `'A'` as lower bound, and `'Z'-'A'+1` as length.

Comment: Linq is wonderful and all, but must it really be used everywhere? Or am I just old-fashioned?

Comment: @David Heffernan : I believe this is up to a developer, I like LINQ syntax and since it does not make significant impact on performance especially on such small data sets as in this case - I would use it since like it, nothing more.

Comment: I just find it unreadable for something like this. Probably my problem. What's clearly wrong though is that your code sets charactersCount to 25.

Comment: I would rather type `"ABCD...YZ"` any day. And do it quicker too.

Comment: Looks like it should be 26, just looked into the ASCII table on MSDN (sorry I'm not a native English speaker so haven't English characters count in mind)

Answer (score 2):

There's no built in way to get a list of strings that correspond to each character. You can get an IEnumerable with the following code, which will probably suit your purposes. You could also just stick with the array in the from section.

```
var letters = from letter in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray()
              select letter.ToString();
```

Comment: Why the unnecessary call to `ToCharArray()`? `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way -

```
  int start = (int) 'A';
  int end = (int) 'Z';

  List<char> letters = new List<char>();

  for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
  {
    letters.Add((char)i);  
  }
```

Same way but less code -

```
IEnumerable<char> linqLetters = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start + 1).Select(t => (char)t);
```

Comment: Why use `int`? Why not loop on a `char`? The real simplest way doesn't have casts.

Answer (score 0):

Generate string and convert to array

```
string str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //create characters
char[] arr;  //create array
arr = str.ToCharArray(0, 26); //You can change the number to adjust this list
```

Get the value in the array

```
char getchar = arr[17];//get "r"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please use the edit button and add some explanation to your answer to make it a better answer. you can also read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). also, the question only wants to list the English alphabet, not numbers. so you may reconsider your answer according to the question requirement.

Comment: I am learning : )